# How to getBounds in react native maps

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to check the boundaries of my map, so that i can apply cluster according to the boundaries.
`var bounds = map.getBounds();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast(); // LatLng of the north-east corner
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest(); // LatLng of the south-west corner`

Answer (score 2):

You can use getMapBoundaries
const data = await map.current.getMapBoundaries();

<MapView ref={map}

Answer (score 0):

I have cleared my issue by finding the zoom level through the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta.

`let zoom = Math.round(Math.log(360 / region.longitudeDelta) / Math.LN2);
 this.zoom = zoom;`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

```js
const getBoundingBox = (region) => ([
  region.longitude - region.longitudeDelta, // westLng - min lng
  region.latitude - region.latitudeDelta, // southLat - min lat
  region.longitude + region.longitudeDelta, // eastLng - max lng
  region.latitude + region.latitudeDelta // northLat - max lat
])
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it is very inaccurate. Because of the spherical shape of the earth, the distances of the region's center to the corners of the bounding box are not equal and therefore not half of the deltas.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getBoundByRegion = (region, scale = 1) => {
  /*
   * Latitude : max/min +90 to -90
   * Longitude : max/min +180 to -180
   */

  const latOffset = (region.latitudeDelta / 2) * scale;
  const lngD =
    region.longitudeDelta < -180
      ? 360 + region.longitudeDelta
      : region.longitudeDelta;
  const lngOffset = (lngD / 2) * scale;

  return {
    minLng: calcMinLngByOffset(region.longitude, lngOffset), // westLng - min lng
    minLat: calcMinLatByOffset(region.latitude, latOffset), // southLat - min lat
    maxLng: calcMaxLngByOffset(region.longitude, lngOffset), // eastLng - max lng
    maxLat: calcMaxLatByOffset(region.latitude, latOffset), // northLat - max lat
  };
};

const calcMinLatByOffset = (lng: number, offset: number) => {
  const factValue = lng - offset;
  if (factValue < -90) {
    return (90 + offset) * -1;
  }
  return factValue;
};

const calcMaxLatByOffset = (lng: number, offset: number) => {
  const factValue = lng + offset;
  if (90 < factValue) {
    return (90 - offset) * -1;
  }
  return factValue;
};

const calcMinLngByOffset = (lng: number, offset: number) => {
  const factValue = lng - offset;
  if (factValue < -180) {
    return (180 + offset) * -1;
  }
  return factValue;
};

const calcMaxLngByOffset = (lng: number, offset: number) => {
  const factValue = lng + offset;
  if (180 < factValue) {
    return (180 - offset) * -1;
  }
  return factValue;
};
```

credit: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/356